# Path-based Routing de paǵinas web estáticas en s3

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

Tengo varias páginas web estáticas alojadas en buckets de **S3**.

Por otro lado tengo un subdominio:

```
apps.dominio.com
```

en **Route 53**.

Mi idea es conseguir redireccionar mediante path a los distintos buckets de S3. Por ejemplo:

```
apps.dominio.com/app1 --> Redirige al bucket que contiene la app1.
apps.dominio.com/app2 --> Redirige al bucket que contiene la app2.
```

Investigando, he visto que no es posible hacerlo a través de ELB(Load Balancers) ya que estos se pueden asociar únicamente a instancias EC2.

En este [post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=61191) comentan que la mejor opción es usar **`CloudFront`**, aunque no estoy seguro de que sirva exactamente para el caso que planteo.

¿Es posible realizar el redireccionamiento comentado? ¿A través de qué herramientas/servicios de AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Logré obtener el resultado esperado. Explico las herramientas utilizadas y los pasos que (a grandes rasgos) hay que tomar:

**Servicios de AWS**

- S3
- CloudFront
- Route 53

**Pasos**

Lo primero es crear un `bucket` en **`S3`**, llamarlo **app.dominio.com** y configurarlo para servir páginas web estáticas.

A continuación creamos los directorios `app1, app2, masapps,...` en nuestro bucket y arrojar nuestro contenido estático en ellas.

En CloudFront creamos una distribución que apuntará a la URL del [Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060394/cloudfront-s3-website-the-specified-key-does-not-exist-when-an-implicit-ind) que proporciona el bucket de **S3**.

En nuestros archivos html hay que tener cuidado con los `js` y `css` que carguemos. Si usamos `/miarchivo.js` este apuntará a la raíz y no a (`/app, /app1,` según el caso) y nuestro sitio no funcionará correctamente.

Finalmente en Route 53 podemos crear un registro `A` y/o `AAAA` que apunte a nuestra distribución de CloudFront.

**NOTA**

CloudFront no es necesario, ya que en Route 53 podemos crear un registro de Alias para el bucket, pero se ha usado debido a las ventajas que ofrece su uso.